# Show custom form after uninstall confirmation message

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

For now, before uninstalling, I show a custom form, which allows users to select additional components to remove during uninstalling. It is shown in the `InitializeUninstall` event, so, it is shown before uninstall confirmation. But now, I want to show it after the confirmation message, but before the actual uninstall process will start (since it decides what should be removed).
So, what can I use to do that? Is there any step or event, which occurs between confirmation and the actual uninstall? Or can I somehow suspend the uninstall process?

Comment: The `InitializeUninstallProgressForm` event is what you're looking for.

Comment: Will uninstalling process suspended, while this event is active (if i will show form, and wait for its result)?

Comment: I guess so, if you show that form as modal (by the `ShowModal` method).